# Select all child div tags in all parents div tags

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select all children classes `attribute(tbox,tarea,cts,tox)` inside of all parents.

This is my code:

```
<div class='cts'>

var s = $('div.cts').children().attr('class');
alert(s);
```

But it shows only the first parent first child class attribute:

```
<fieldset id="tt">
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tss">
            <input type="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tox">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: please tidy up code and provide the js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find()`

```
$('.cts'.find('*').each(function(){

    var attr = $(this).attr('class');

    if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {

       alert($(this).attr('myattr'));  
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` to get an array.

```
var s = $('div.cts').children().map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var classes = ('div.cts *').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
});
```

`classes` will be an array of class names.

Answer (score 0):

.attr() only returns the first one, but you can do this to get an array of the values

```
var classes = []

$('div.cts').children().each(function(){
    classes.push(attr('class'));
});

alert(classes);
```